# How can i keep value of object same after block completion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

I am using block to download file. I need to get value of object after block completion and it should be same as start of block.

Please check code :

```
-(void)startDownloadFile:(NSDictionary *)dict withAllFile:(NSMutableArray *)arr withTable:(UITableView *)tableView{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[arr indexOfObject:dict] inSection:0];
    AttchmentCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   [manager startDownloadCallWithRequestJson:dictDownloadRequest withCompletion:^(NSString *strResponce, NSDictionary *RESPONSE_DATA) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@",cell.lblName.text); // cell overites its value of last method
            [cell.downloadButton completeProgressing];

    }];
}
```

I am calling this method :

```
    [self startDownloadFile:arr[0] withAllFile:arr withTable:tableView];
 [self startDownloadFile:arr[1] withAllFile:arr withTable:tableView];
```

**Problem :**

I am always getting cell value of second block arr[1].

**Expected :**

If second call (arr[1]) block complates I need to get cell two.
If first call (arr[0]) block complates I need to get cell first.

Hope you will clear about my problem.

Comment: Try with define a variable with __block,

Comment: __block AttchmentCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: @AshokPolu not working

Comment: keep first two lines inside your "startDownload" method because your not performing any operation before start download, try now

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct to get a cell based on index path before the asynchronous operation and make a change to that cell after the asynchronous operation, because by that time the cell at that index path may be a different cell, and you may therefore be changing the wrong cell.

Compute the cell based on index path after the asynchronous operation (i.e. inside the block dispatched to main queue).

Comment: Hi my purpose is to change before and after asynchronous block.. before i need to change cell to show download is started and after finish need to show download complete